# How to fix memory leak c#

Tags: c#

When i ran my app after few seconds app gets about 144 MB memory and app crash how can i fix that I want to do my operation fast but my app crash so fast
Sorry for my English

```
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
      {
          //inside AsynchCallBack method for request.BeginGetResponse()
          var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);

          string html;
          using (var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
          using (var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
          {
              html = readStream.ReadToEnd();
          }

          Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
     }, null
   );
}
```

So I expect to use more memory without crash app

Comment: Can you please the text of exact exception you're getting? This program does not seem to leak any memory.

Comment: How is the period of the timer calling `timer4_Tick` compared to the average run time of the method? If it is shorter, the web requests will pile up. Consider stopping the timer at the start of the method and restarting it at the end.

Comment: So the final result [link](https://imgur.com/a/o2VSF3F)

Comment: Is there any way using more memory without app crash

Comment: @HristoIvanov Does your memory afford requested memory size for your app, For example 16 gb ram that i have and ı try your code for just web request, 1GB that i have and there is no app crush . Could you check your available memory limit.

Comment: Yes i think 8gb ram

Comment: I have 8 gb so there is no problem

Comment: To inspect memory leaks and their causes, use a memory profiler. There are plenty of them, even Visual Studio has one.

Comment: The memory uptick is just JIT nothing to do with why your app is crashing. Are you getting a stack overflow exception? My you timer is probably not set correctly I don't think this has anything to do with memory.

Answer (score 0):

Why you think you have memory leak?
The fact, that "after few seconds app gets about 144 MB memory" does not mean that it is leaking. Garbage collector may start later.

More likely it crashes due to some other unhandled exception.

One more thing you can do is  limit the scope of "var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar)". It implements IDisposable. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse?view=netframework-4.8